# Ruby has_many :through Association to python django

Tags: python-3.x, django, ruby

How to write this in django.There are two class models:users and advertiser_users.

```
 has_many :users, through: :advertiser_users
```

Answer (score 0):

I could write a longer answer but I'd be repeating what is in the [Django Many to Many guide. Have a look at that.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Your question should show some attempt at solving the problem. [Have a read of the Stack Overflow Guide How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)